# Turning a Visual Studio C# Project into a setup file

Tags: c#, .net, installation

I have a program written in c# using visual studio 2010 ultimate, and I want to be able to deploy the program into a setup file, or an installer file.

I need the setup file such that I can run and install my program on any windows machine, just like any other piece of software.

How do I go about building/deploying the project in this manner??

Comment: Have you tried to Google "Visual Studio setup deploy"?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Check the FAQ for some guidelines on how to get most out of our community, and how to contribute most to our community.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to create a MSI install package, you can do so using [a Setup Project](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/19x10e5c%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). See [this overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/206sadcd%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) for various walkthroughs how to create/configure the project for different scenarios.

The Setup project works for simple install scenarios, but is not fit for more advanced tasks. If your needs exceeds the capabilities of a set up project, you can look at [WiX](http://wixtoolset.org/).

Comment: Thanks dude! This is perfect. Nice simple way to create an install package.

Answer (score 1):

Or, you might want to take a look at [NSIS](http://nsis.sf.net) - it's easier on the beginners, and has a lot of great tutorials and examples.

For the ultimate control and generation of MSI install packages, you might want to take a look at [WiX](http://wix.sf.net) - it has a far greater functionality than Visual Studio's Setup Projects.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is to use the native tool for Visual Studio 2010: [ClickOnce](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/31kztyey.aspx)